# AlreadyExistsError :Another metric with the same name already exists . should i delete whole keras folder /uninstall keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

**this is error that shows **
should i delete keras folder in python ?

```
    AlreadyExistsError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4132/4279258018.py in <module>
          1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    ----> 2 from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
    
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py in <module>
          6 import sys as _sys
          7 
    ----> 8 from keras import __version__
          9 from keras.api._v2.keras import __internal__
         10 from keras.api._v2.keras import activations
    
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
         23 
         24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
    ---> 25 from keras import models
         26 
         27 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
    
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in <module>
         18 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
         19 from keras import backend
    ---> 20 from keras import metrics as metrics_module
         21 from keras import optimizer_v1
         22 from keras.engine import functional
    
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py in <module>
         24 
         25 import numpy as np
    ---> 26 from keras import activations
         27 from keras import backend
         28 from keras.engine import base_layer
    
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py in <module>
         18 
         19 from keras import backend
    ---> 20 from keras.layers import advanced_activations
         21 from keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
         22 from keras.utils.generic_utils import serialize_keras_object
    
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py in <module>
         21 
         22 # Generic layers.
    ---> 23 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
         24 from keras.engine.input_layer import InputLayer
         25 from keras.engine.input_spec import InputSpec
    
    ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in <module>
         19 from keras import backend
         20 from keras.distribute import distributed_training_utils
    ---> 21 from keras.engine import base_layer
         22 from keras.engine import keras_tensor
         23 from keras.engine import node as node_module
```

AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.

Comment: This traceback does not make any sense, please include the full traceback without any edits.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy traceback is bigger and can't add the whole thing here for editing purposes . sorry.

Comment: In that case you can edit the top of the traceback but not the bottom, without that kind of information people will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and uninstalled everything related to tensorflow , keras and deleted all the files in APPdata and reinstalled everything. And it solved my problem .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you installed both keras and tensoflow, due to conflict, My solution is uninstall keras.

Comment: It did not resolve issue for me. I started getting another error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is post in [github/keras/issues/15579](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15579)
It is a problem with keras 2.7. Downgrade to keras 2.6 solves the issue.